# How can I uninstall Python language server (was installed by VS Intellicode extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-language-server

I installed Visual Studio Intellicode extension in my VS Code (which installed Python language server).
I did some testing and decided to uninstall Visual Studio Intellicode extension, which I did.

But I can't find Python Language server to uninstall.
How can I uninstall Python language server?

Thanks in advance,

JM

Comment: what OS are you running? have you tried to remove the package manually from the `/extensions` directory (by simply deleting the folder)? Btw. could you please provide a link to the extension?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro SP1 w/all updates.No, I only find one python directory inside the extensions dir. I don't know if that is the language server or just the python support embedded in VS Code.

Comment: Just search for Intellicode in the extensions panel on VS Code.

Comment: I'm running Linux and I was able to uninstall the complete `Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview` extension (after I installed it and reloaded vscode to reproduce your issue). This could be a problem with Windows maybe, so sorry.

Comment: I was also able to uninstall the VS Intellicode extension. My problem is with the Python Language server it installed.

Comment: yes, I understood. I mean I didn't have that problem after removing Intellicode.

Comment: "one does not simply remove language server" :) It creates folder in python extension. I deleted the folder but guess what, next time it recreated and reinstalled itself. So I uninstalled entire VS code, deleted all its data including extensions and settings and reinstalled, I copied back my settings and language server reinstalled itself. Now I'm testing "python.jediEnabled" as proposed by @jmatos

Answer (score 2):

I was able to bypass the language server by re-enabling the "python.jediEnabled" to true.